# Logrotate with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

so i would like to create a ansible playbook that installs logrotate on all the servers in company. Also configs them to to set logs to be backed up weekly and then deleted a week after. So each week it makes a new log, backups last week log and on the third week it deletes the first one and repeats.

So far i have found this but we do not use nginx. And it does not do exactly what i want. My knowledge in playbooks is quite limited so if someone could help with it would be awesome. Also i need it to check if the server has tomcat, apache or wildfly and then takes those logs.

```
logrotate_scripts:
  - name: nginx-options
    path: /var/log/nginx/options.log
      options:
      - daily
      - weekly
      - size 25M
      - rotate 7
      - missingok
      - compress
      - delaycompress
      - copytruncate
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's use [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html#blockinfile-insert-update-remove-a-text-block-surrounded-by-marker-lines). For example, the task

```yaml
    - blockinfile:
        path: "/etc/logrotate.d/{{ item.path }}"
        block: "{{ item.conf }}"
        create: true
      loop: "{{ lp_logrotate_confd }}"
```

with the variable

```yaml
    lp_logrotate_confd:
      - path: ansible
        conf: |
          /var/log/ansible.log {
                 weekly
                 rotate 3
                 size 10M
                 compress
                 delaycompress
          }
```

creates

```bash
shell> cat /etc/logrotate.d/ansible 
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
/var/log/ansible.log {
       weekly
       rotate 3
       size 10M
       compress
       delaycompress
}
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Add items to the list and fit the configuration data to your needs. For your convenience, the code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/logrotate.yml).

Comment: Thanks ill have to process this i simply have no clue what does what in here.

Comment: I like your solution better than using an Ansible Galaxy contributed role e.g. https://galaxy.ansible.com/nickhammond/logrotate :)